# Rewrite Rule Not is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

Please let me know what is the problem in my htaccess Rewrite Rule for php files.

```
 #Options +FollowSymLinks
 # RewriteEngine On
 # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain.com$ [NC]
 # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !cosa
 # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !schools
 # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/cosa/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In the above, I transfer my website to new folder called cosa and I want to redirect all the links to it but not "schools"

I put two ! statement one for cosa itself to avoid page redirect itself and other for folder called schools.

When I run this, like mydomain.com/schools it forwarding to mydomain.com/cosa/schools

what I want is

```
If type mydomain.com/abc shall goes to mydomain.com/cosa/abc
If type mydomain.com/xyz shall goes to mydomain.com/cosa/xyz
If type mydomain.com/news shall goes to mydomain.com/cosa/news
If type mydomain.com/events shall goes to mydomain.com/cosa/events
```

But when enter schools like

```
If type mydomain.com/schools it should be same mydomain.com/schools
```

please let me know where is the problem in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !cosa
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !schools
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cosa
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/schools
```

Comment: Woow... works excatly as I need... Could you please also tell me how to get the index page on the root. Like if i type www.mydomain.com I need to get www.mydomain.com/index.php

Comment: @user3477550 `%{REQUEST_URI} !^/` and `%{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php`

Comment: its working but the previous rule is showing file not found like If type mydomain.com/abc shall goes to mydomain.com/cosa/abc but its showing 404 file not found.

Comment: @user3477550 Try changing the `!^/` to `!^/$` or, it that doesn't work; remove that statement completely.

Comment: Thank you dear its working purfectly by chaing to !^/$. This really helps me alot.. God bless you..